# Is there a way to have Visual Web Developer ignore build errors?

Tags: visual-web-developer

I'm using MS's VWD to edit some .aspx files in our website (I'm opening it as a website, not a project/solution).

I have some temporary files just for testing and some generate Build errors in VWD 2010.

But VWD won't let me "run" other pages in the website with those Build Errors present.

Is there a way to get it to IGNORE them?

Answer (score 3):

Im using Visual web developer express,
but assume the the settings are the same.

1. click on TOOLS on the MENUBAR
2. click on OPTIONS when the TOOLS menu drops down
3. click on SHOW ALL SETTINGS when the OPTIONS window appears
4. click on PROJECTS AND SOLUTIONS in the LEFT hand panel
5. click on BUILD AND RUN in the projects and solutions drop down
6. in the rigt hand panel, look for the text "On Run, when build or deployment errors occur:"
7. change it to "PROMPT TO LAUNCH"
8. click OKAY button to save changes

Voila.